# Accuracy is different between "tune" and "predict" in R

Tags: r

I am making SVM which will differentiate beforehand and afterward of track maintenance using on-board accelerometer on train car. There is focused section and I extracted the acceleration data corresponding to that section. Each run should take around 3 minutes to pass that section, so considering that sampling rate of accelerometer is around 1600/s, there are around 3min * 60sec * 1600/s = 288,000 records of acceleration data for each run. Then I calculate variance, maximum, minimum, mean, standard deviation and most frequent value of those acceleration records of each run. There are around 250 runs, so I made the dataset of those calculated value of 250 runs. Then also I put classification of beforehand and afterward of track maintenance, depending on the maintenance record and the date of each run.

Using this, I tried to make SVM as I mentioned. At first, I tried to find optimal parameters of gamma and cost in gaussian kernel function, so I used "tune" to do grid search. Then I got the result as follow:

```
> source("grid_search.R")
[gamma = 1 , cost = 10 ]
- best parameters:
gamma = 1.584893 ; cost = 25.11886 ;
accuracy: 88.54935 %
```

Also "grid_search.R" is as follow:

```
gamma <- 10^(0.0)
cost  <- 10^(1.0)
gammaRange <- 10^seq(log10(gamma)-1,log10(gamma)+1,length=11)[2:10]
costRange  <- 10^seq(log10(cost)-1 ,log10(cost)+1 ,length=11)[2:10]
t <- tune.svm(Category ~ ., data = X, gamma=gammaRange, cost=costRange,
          tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling="cross", cross=8))
cat("[gamma =", gamma, ", cost =" , cost , "]\n")
cat("- best parameters:\n")
cat("gamma =", t$best.parameters$gamma, "; cost =", t$best.parameters$cost, ";\n")
cat("accuracy:", 100 - t$best.performance * 100, "%\n\n")
plot(t, transform.x=log10, transform.y=log10, zlim=c(0,0.1))
```

After that, using "svm" with the parameter "gamma = 1.584893 ; cost = 25.11886 ;" found as above, I trained SVM and tried to predict to classify the data which is used for training SVM as following:

```
gamma = 1.584893 ; cost = 25.11886;
model <- svm(Category ~ ., data = X, gamma=gamma, cost=cost)
pred <- predict(model, X)
table(pred, X[,13])
```

And I got result as following matrix:

```
pred     after before
after      47    2
before     1    185
```

My question is: Depending on the matrix above, accuracy can be said as
1 - (1 + 2)/(47 + 2 + 1 + 185) = 0.987234 (98.7%)

But I also got "accuracy: 88.54935 %" as a result of "tune" when I got optimal parameters such as "gamma = 1.584893 ; cost = 25.11886;".

Comment: Parameter tuning is done by multiple data sets (eg k-fold cross validation) while model fitting is on a single data set. The results could be different?

Comment: @JaehyeonKim It makes a sense, Thanks!